# Правильный способ проверки входных аргументов на корректность

Tags: c#, функции, исключения, методы, проверка

У меня  есть несколько методов. Необходимо, чтобы каждый из них проверял, что ему передают корректные по диапазону значений аргументы, прежде чем выполнял полезную работу.

```
class MyClass
{
    public void SomeMethod1(string a, int b){};
    public void SomeMethod2(string a, int b, float c){};
}
```

Вот статический метод, который проверяет строковой аргумент на непустоту:

```
static void CheckStringArgument(string arg, string argName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arg))
            throw new ArgumentException($"{argName} is null or empty or white space");
}
```

**Вопрос: лучше эту проверку проводить в отдельном методе (CheckStringArgument) или внутри самого метода?**

Иными словами, что более предпочтительнее:

Вариант 1:

```
public void SomeMethod1(string a, int b)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a))
            throw new ArgumentException($"{a} is null or empty or white space");
     // .......
};
```

Или Вариант 2:

```
public void SomeMethod1(string a, int b)
{
    CheckStringArgument(a, nameof(a));
    // .....
};
```

Comment: вы открыли для себя [Code Contracts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/code-contracts)

Comment: разница между вашими вариантами зависит от того, будет ли компилятор инлайнить вызовы ваших функций. Если нет, то вариант 2 будет чуть чуть медленней работать из за лишнего вызова функции

Comment: Если метод делает 2 действия, то это нарушает Принцип единственности ответственности. Лучше сделать метод, который вызывает SomeMethod1 только для корректных данных.

Comment: @becouse так тот новый метод также буде делать 2 действия - проверку и вызов `SomeMethod1`

Comment: ну и в довесок, если у вас класс `MyClass` приватный, то есть он не используется внешними клиентами и вы контролируете все его вызовы, то, возможно вам проверка в нем в принципе не нужна.

Comment: вот рекомендации MS о [проверке параметров метода](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/parameter-design#validating-arguments)

Comment: @tym32167 нет, т.к. это обращение к реализации, но не сама реализация.